# What is the least prime $p$, such that $[p-1000,p+1000]$ does not contain a prime $\ne p$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I am looking for the least prime number $p$, such that the interval $[p-1000,p+1000]$ contains no prime except $p$. In other words, the prime nearest to
$p$ has a distance $>1000$ to $p$.

I found a table for prime gaps, giving the lower bound $1.6\times 10^{15}$ for $p$. An example for
a $p$ satisfying the condition is $10^{99}+1005697$. The neighbour primes are
$10^{99}+1004269$ and $10^{99}+1007193$, but this won't be the least example.

I do not know whether a search for such primes has been made, or if the distance to the
nearest prime (instead the distance of the next prime) has been studied
intensively.

- Does anyone know a good candidate for $p$ ?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FactorialPrime.html says $p\ge11$

Comment: My feeling is that this problem is intractable.

Comment: 619720807735926015780830909643132438170160120545916897703180508077261 is a much lower example than my initial one, but still very large (69 digits).

Comment: https://oeis.org/A087770

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap

Comment: A not too big change to standard prime gap finding code can turn some up, but I suspect finding the minimal value will be a huge amount of work. Some smaller inputs than your examples include the nicely symmetrical PRP50 28033*113#/30+4 (-1020 +1020).  Even smaller are PRP49 111481*109#/30-724; PRP48 1252123*107#/30+192; PRP46 42461*109#/3210+254.  I'm sure these are far larger than the minimal p.

Comment: Your results are much better than my new record $10^{59}+611419053$, which took me a very long time to find by brute force. I should focus on the primorials. Thank you for your results, Dana!