# What is the smallest prime $p$ such that the next prime is greater than $p+2000\ $?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I studied this site

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap

and wondered if the smallest prime gap greater than $2000$ can still be determined, in other words :

> Which is the smallest prime $p$, such that
>   $q-p>2000$, where $p$ and $q$ are consecutive primes ?

Clearly, $1.4\times 10^{18}$ is a lower bound for $p$, as the calculated prime gaps show.

I tried to estimate the magnitude of the smallest prime gap with difference
$2002$, but the useful estimations refer to the definition $g_n=p_{n+1}-p_n$.
I did not manage to estimate the desired result with the given estimates for
$g_n$ and I think they are far too big.

An example with $61$ digits is $$p=149\# \times 1290 \ + \ 8849$$

```
s=prod(j=1,35,prime(j))*1290+8849;t=nextprime(s+1);print(isprime(s,2),"   ",is
prime(t,2),"    ",t-s,"    ",truncate(log(s)/log(10)+1))
1   1    2042    61
```

Comment: I think that [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1406191/11619) deserves to be linked here, so I just added it :-)

Comment: The numbers seem to be large, for 220 the smallest primes are 122164747 and 122164969. I can't get past this :(

Comment: Hmm i think this is too close to questions like p-q = 2. So i think this Cannot be estimated or calculated efficiently. Let me know if im wrong plz !!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you care about this, or is this just a tedious exercise? There is no known pattern for the "least" such gap.

Comment: @dream this is the reason I ask the question. Someone may have better candidates.

Comment: @thomas I hoped that there is at least a relatively tight estimate, but maybe this is not the case.

Comment: @Peter I tried to do it for larger numbers but my system crashed :(

Comment: The smallest currently known gap of length exactly 2002 has 33 digits.  The smallest I see with gap >2000 has 30 digits.  These are not minimal numbers.  All gaps under 4e18 have been examined and we're still at 1476 for the largest definitive first occurrence.  No new results since 2009.  This is an amazingly large computational task. TOeS's analysis to the 4e18 range used time on multiple large clusters.

Comment: The minimum is 4e18 rather than 1.4e18, as TOeS has exhaustively tested to that limit without finding anything.

For some smaller examples, though much larger than a minimum: PRP47 629363*107#/30-1304.  Much smaller is the 30 digit 631317731251295254677161237269 which is the smallest currently known gap start with length > 2000.  Its merit is under 30, so we ought to be able to find something smaller.

Comment: @Dana thanks again for the info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't go all the way to 2000 but it addresses your problem. Apparently it is hard to do it exhaustively. It has only been done for primes under $10^{18}$ and the gap they found is $1476$

http://primerecords.dk/primegaps/maximal.htm

Answer (score 4):

I would like to ammend my previous (edited) estimate to a more conservative one: betwen $1.97\times 10^{19}$ and $7.02\times 10^{22},$ with the most likely value being close to $1.18\times 10^{21},$ based purely on data from @dREaM's link (or equivalently [this one](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/GapsTable.html)), but this is highly speculative. Speculation based on following observations:

```
cc={{0,2},{1,3},{3,7},{5,23},{7,89},{13,113},{17,523},{19,887},{21,1129},{33,1327},{35,9551},{43,15683},{51,19609},{71,31397},{85,155921},{95,360653},{111,370261},{113,492113},{117,1349533},{131,1357201},{147,2010733},{153,4652353},{179,17051707},{209,20831323},{219,47326693},{221,122164747},{233,189695659},{247,191912783},{249,387096133},{281,436273009},{287,1294268491},{291,1453168141},{319,2300942549},{335,3842610773},{353,4302407359},{381,10726904659},{383,20678048297},{393,22367084959},{455,25056082087},{463,42652618343},{467,127976334671},{473,182226896239},{485,241160624143},{489,297501075799},{499,303371455241},{513,304599508537},{515,416608695821},{531,461690510011},{533,614487453523},{539,738832927927},{581,1346294310749},{587,1408695493609},{601,1968188556461},{651,2614941710599},{673,7177162611713},{715,13829048559701},{765,19581334192423},{777,42842283925351},{803,90874329411493},{805,171231342420521},{905,218209405436543},{915,1189459969825483},{923,1686994940955803},{1131,1693182318746371},{1183,43841547845541059},{1197,55350776431903243},{1219,80873624627234849},{1223,203986478517455989},{1247,218034721194214273},{1271,305405826521087869},{1327,352521223451364323},{1355,401429925999153707},{1369,418032645936712127},{1441,804212830686677669},{1475,1425172824437699411}}

With[{c = 4}, ListLinePlot[{(Sqrt@# & /@ (Transpose@cc)[[1]]), -Log[ 
Log[RiemannR@N[#] - Sqrt@#]/#] & /@ ((Transpose@cc)[[2]]), (#/
2 + c & /@ Range@(2 Sqrt@2000)), (#/2 - c & /@ Range@(2 Sqrt@2000)), (#/2 
& /@ Range@(2 Sqrt@2000))}, FillingStyle -> {Directive[{Opacity[.25], 
ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[1]]}]} , PlotStyle -> {{}, {}, {Opacity[0]}, 
{Opacity[0]}, {Darker@Blue, Thin, Dashed}}, Filling -> {3 -> {4}}, 
Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {0, Automatic}}]]
```

[image]

```
x /. With[{c = 4}, Table[FindRoot[-Log[Log[-Sqrt@x + RiemannR@N[x]]/
    x] == (#/2 + cc &@(2 Sqrt@2000)), {x, 1000}], {cc, {-c, 0, c}}]]

(*{1.96873*10^19, 1.18074*10^21, 7.02452*10^22}*)
```

This is of course a huge search area, but is as speculatively tight as possible, I think, given the data known to date. I should be fairly surprised if the value lies significantly outside of these bounds. If you find anything, I should be interested in the results you achieve. Anyway, should give you fairly reasonable bounds in which to search.

## Update

In responsse to @DanaJ's comment below, for *proven* first occurrances, of course uyou will have to start the search at $4\times10^{18},$ since that is the current exhaustive search limit. The upper bound is then $\approx 8.247\times 10^{32}$ [*see here*](http://www.trnicely.net/gaps/g2k.html).

However, I am cannot find any reason to suggest that the merit will be as low as $\approx 35,$ despite current max merits known. Plotting the value of increasing merits for first known occurrances:

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[{Transpose@{Sqrt@cc[[All, 1]], 
N[#[[1]]/Log@#[[2]]] & /@ cc}, # - Sqrt@# & /@ Range@Sqrt@2000, # & /@ 
Range@Sqrt@2000, # - (Sqrt@#)/2 & /@ Range@Sqrt@2000}, 
FillingStyle -> {Directive[{Opacity[.25], 
ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[1]]}]}, PlotStyle -> 
{{Darker@ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[1]]}, {Opacity[0]}, 
{Opacity[0]}, {Darker@Blue, Thin, Dashed}, {Opacity[0]}}, 
Filling -> {3 -> {4}, 2 -> {4}}, Frame -> True]
```

shows very clear statistical trends which suggest that the merit at $g_n\geq 2000$ yields similar estimated bounds as given in first part of answer, but using completely different methods, with the following merit min, expected & max estimates:

```
N@{# - Sqrt@# &@Sqrt@2000, # - Sqrt@#/2 &@Sqrt@2000, # &@Sqrt@2000}
(*{38.034, 41.3777, 44.7214}*)
```

giving estimated prime ranges of

```
Flatten[x /. NSolve[2000/Log[x] == #, x] & /@ Reverse@{# - Sqrt@# 
&@Sqrt@2000, # - Sqrt@#/2 &@Sqrt@2000, # &@ Sqrt@2000}]

(*{2.64387*10^19, 9.81156*10^20, 6.8738*10^22}*)
```

which are in clear agreement with initial estimates.

Of course, one could be a little more conservative with these estimates, going for something like

```
Flatten[x /. NSolve[2000/Log[x] == #, x] & /@ Reverse@{# - (Sqrt@# + 
Log@Log@#) &@ Sqrt@2000, # - (Sqrt@# + Log@Log@#/4)/2 &@
Sqrt@2000, # + Log@Log@# &@Sqrt@2000}] 

(*{7.23125*10^18, 1.19329*10^21, 4.65612*10^23}*)
```

but I almost certainly don't think it is necessary to go as high as $6.9\times 10^{24}.$ Only time will tell, of course, and the rate at reaseach in this area and the technology to support it are going, I shouldn't think we will have too long to wait before we get a definitive answer to your question :)

Comment: This is great, but a problem with the lower limit is that unless you can *prove* the gap start must be higher than that number, you need to start at 4e18 (the current limit of exhaustive search) or you would just have a first known occurrence gap rather than a true first occurrence.  Your lower limit gives a merit of 45.06, while your high limit has a merit of 38.06.  Those are some really high merits.  35 merits would be about 6.9 x 10^24.

Comment: @DanaJ please see update.

Comment: Great stuff @martin.  Thanks for this analysis!  I agree that there doesn't seem to be any reason those merits aren't possible -- mostly it's just a wow reaction to how hard they are to find.

Comment: @DanaJ I noticed your name on the tables BTW - well done - that is some achievement! :)  Great answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/897442/101417) too (+1) - trying to impliment your suggestions in _Mathematica_, but am only at [v basic stages](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92294/finding-large-prime-gaps) so far! ;)

Comment: @DanaJ The maximum merit up to $n$ is conjectured to grow like $\log n$, which is essentially [Cramér's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramér%27s_conjecture), so there is heuristic reason to believe it will be closer to $40$.  It is actually known to diverge to infinity, albeit pretty slowly (the first result is due to Westzynthius in 1931, but there has been a [burst of](http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.4505) [recent activity](http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.5110) in this area).

Answer (score 1):

Using my conjecture [A Conjecture Sharper than Cramér's and Firoozbakht's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1674305/a-conjecture-sharper-than-cram%c3%a9rs-and-firoozbakhts]) $g_n<(p_n/n)^2 < (\log{(p_n)-1})^2$ and just solving with $g_n = 2000$ we get $\exp{(\sqrt{g_n}+1)} < p_n = 7.187 * 10^{19}$. For $g_n = 2100$ we get $p_n = 2.168 * 10^{20}$.So, if it happen later than this I will be shocked because of it proving a failure to the conjecture with a very small prime.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wolf's conjecture](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeGaps.html), the first occurrence of prime gap $g$ is somewhere near the prime $p$ given by
$$
p \approx \sqrt{g}\exp(\sqrt{g}).
$$
(This is equation $(67)$ in Wolf's paper [arXiv:1102.0481](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.0481).)

Substituting the prime gap size $g=2000$, we could expect to see such a gap near 
$$
p \approx \sqrt{2000}\exp(\sqrt{2000}) \approx 1.18\cdot10^{21}.
$$